# dask dataframe to_parquet throws error

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to save task dataframe to parquet on HDFS. However it fails with error :Exception: TypeError('expected list of bytes',)

I am also providing object_encoding argument as {"anomaly":"json","sensor_name":"json"}.

Here is the columns in dataframe: Index(['original_value', 'anomaly', 'anomaly_bin', 'sensor_name'], dtype='object')

Columns sensor_name and anomaly are string. Other columns are float.

eg: [18.0 'N' 0.0 'settemp']

I also tried to save it as CSV in HDFS but the api failed with error: Exception: ValueError('url type not understood:
Path to CSV as: hdfs://ip:port/some path

It will be great if some one can guide me in right direction.

Comment: If anomaly and sensor_name are always strings, I would suggest using utf8 encoding, which is the default.

Comment: Thanks mdurant for your reply. I made the changes as per your suggestion but it still fails with same error.

Comment: Which of the two errors do you still get?
For the url not understood, this could be simply that hdfs3 is not installed - but it would be easier to tell if you included the full traceback.

Comment: The issue of parquet is resolved. I had to explicitly cast all numeric column using dtype api to numpy float.

Comment: The problem of CSV remains. @mdurant, hdfs3 is installed. Even for parquet, Im using HDFS. For now I am going ahead with parquet only. If will check the error with CSV with I ever need to use CSV again.

Comment: Again, it would be super-helpful if you could find out the url seen in the code. This exception occurs if the url is not a string, list, tuple, or set. So what is it?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply @mdurant. I will share the information you enquired about when I try that scenario again.